# SparkJava - API Taking Longer than 20 seconds. Is there a way to tell the client that I'm still processing the request?

Tags: spark-java

I have a service with an SLA of 20+ seconds. Is there a way in SparkJava to send back a 102 to tell the client that I am processing the request without terminating the request?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know there's only one response per request, which is the second parameter of the route. Even on the client side I think you will not find a libray that will handle more than one response per request.

Comment: @LaercioMetzner thanks for confirming. Was hoping there was something like https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Response.html#sendProcessing--.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your server takes more than 20 seconds to answer, you might want to avoid having your clients wait for that long. Also, please note that HTTP status *102 - Processing* will only be handled correctly by WebDAV-compliant clients.

I suggest that you implement a kind of task management API, e.g:

- `POST /tasks`: create a task ID, store task to execute, launch background process to handle task, immediately return task ID to client
- `GET /tasks/:id`: get status of task with ID `:id` - e.g `pending | done | error` - with appropriate result and/or error message depending on state; you could even imagine to send some progress data to show a kind of progress bar to your users
- `DELETE /tasks/:id`: de-register task with ID `:id`, delete results, optionally cancel running task

The main advantage of this approach is that it lets you get rid of client and server timeouts.

The main drawbacks are that:

- it is a bit more involved than the standard request/response mechanism
- you might need a kind of persistent storage to store pending tasks, and a way to delegate long running tasks to some executor service (e.g event bus, message queue)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That the original the original idea (make an asynchronous task execution api) but got shutdown due to how a legacy application would interact with my API unfortunately.